# What is SIP, in plain English?

Tags: sip

I have tried reading the [Wikipedia page for SIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol) but I can't follow at all (incidentally, it is currently marked as too technical).

What exactly is SIP? I understand how it is a protocol for transmitting voice over TCP, but that is not very helpful. Is it like Skype or Google Voice? Do I need a SIP client like Ekiga installed on my computer to use it? Would I be able to call only other people who have such a client running on their computer? Can I call normal phone numbers from a SIP client? Can they call me? Who pays for the calls, and to what company? What will my phone number be? Can I use SIP to make calls from a phone?

Basically, I want a simple, concise explanation of what SIP is, what it does, what it costs (in terms of effort and complexity as well as just money), and what it can and cannot be used for.

Comment: Since I got a close vote, let me justify my question by quoting http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask : "*However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK.*" - I would like others to explain SIP to me.

Comment: SIP is a protocol used by some software/hardware.  Some software can inter-operate, some can't.  There are even alternatives like H.323 that do basically the same thing.

Comment: The concise description is right there in the first line on Wikipedia: "The Session Initiation Protocol (SIP) is a **signaling communications protocol**, widely used for **controlling** multimedia communication sessions such as voice and video calls over Internet Protocol (IP) networks." I've emphasised the bits I feel important.  SIP is one of many protocols that make up VOIP in general and is to do with the creation, management and control of VOIP rather than the actual voice data itself.

Answer (score 3):

@Nicolas is almost (but not quite) correct -

SIP is a VOIP platform. It works over UDP, NOT TCP (this is an important feature and limitation).

It is like Skype and Google-Voice, save that it is an open standard (unlike Skype), and designed primarily for calls (unlike Google Voice which uses Instant Messaging as the basis of the protocol).   It is more powerful then Skype, and in some ways more powerful then Google Voice.

From an end users point of view, SIP appears more as a Client-Server model rather then a P2P model.  (If you get into the technical details this is not necessarily true though)

In order to use it you need a SIP client (like Ekiga or a VOIP phone - VOIP Phones are common) as well as a device/system to handle the calls.

Your ability to call normal phones with SIP is dependent on how the SIP server interconnects.  Usually it is possible as this is one of the basis for the existence of SIP, but it is entirely possible to have a system which does not interconnect with the telephone (ie PSTN) network.

The answers to your last set of questions are all "It depends on the SIP setup".  It should be pointed out here that anyone can set up a SIP server - Asterisk is a common, free example (but there are closed source and other options as well - many which are dedicated hardware).  SIP is often used to interconnect Telcos and route calls - this is extremely common with respect of calling cards.    Also, invariably if you have a Naked DSL connection where your provider provides VOIP calling, this will be running SIP in the backend.

The person who pays for calls would be the person initiating the call or the SIP server associated with making the call.  That said, very often SIP calls between clients connected to the same servers are free save for the Internet bandwidth they use.  When payment is due for calls its generally by agreement between the call SIP server and an upstream provider who provides services to break the call out onto the PSTN (ie regular phone network)

You can only make SIP calls from a SIP device - SIP phones are quite common.  If you want to use a regular phone to make a SIP call you will need a converter box.  These boxes are typically known as "ATA's" or "FXS devices"

It is a lot more complex and expensive to set up a SIP system then a Skype or Google Voice system, however you have a high degree of control including things like -

1. Guarantees of call quality can be implemented.
2. Least Cost and inter-office routing.
3. Privacy and security.
4. Ability to move anywhere and keep the same resources (Skype and Google Voice allow this
   as well)
5. Built on a well defined, open standard
6. SIP Servers often have advanced PABX features like IVR's, call queues, voice messaging,
   Music on Hold, call stepping etc - although this is really not a function of SIP as
   much as the server.

If you call a call center and your call goes to another part of the country or another country, or if it is a large company with multiple offices and complex IVR systems chances are they are using a SIP based system - SIP systems are more-and-more replacing regular PABX systems.

The bits I disagree with with Nicolas are -

1. SIP IS SIP,  there are a basic set of standards that all SIP devices should adhere to,
   so it should be possible to get any devices to interconnect (for example using alaw or
   ulaw coding - the coding used be the regular phone systems).  There are lots and lots
   of add-ons which are not compatible, but it should always be possible to negotiate 
   to a common standard, and/or for a server to translate between standards.
2. Translating to other protocols does not always (or even usually) translate to costs.
   Converting between SIP and IAX is common (IAX is a similar but simpler and not as
   widely adopted protocol).  The same can be said of h.323 and other protocols.  There
   are even ways to interconnect SIP with Skype at no cost.
3. There are FREE SIP providers (who generally allow free calls within their network
   and charge for calls to numbers outside their network).  The limitation here is the
   size of their networks is tiny compared to Skype and the like.
4. SIP requires a SIP server, not a SIP provider.  You can get software servers which
   run on regular computers - like Asterisk and 3CX, as well as SIP PABXs

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a quite good question. It took me some years to reach my current level of understanding. As far as I know, SIP:

- needs SIP devices to communicate with (these can be hardphones or softphones - the latter is e. g. Ekiga)
- needs a SIP provider to which the SIP device connects to
- can communicate only with other SIP devices
- but can be translated via SIP gateways (that are kind of SIP devices as well) to other communication protocols ... so, depending on the SIP provider, one can call even POTS lines
- costs nothing if you are your own SIP provider with installing a SIP server on your home LAN (e. g. Asterisk) ... But then, you can call yourself only, of course
- costs nothing for "internal" calls, if the SIP provider does not charge this
- costs definitely when using gateway routes to other protocols (this implies that your SIP provider registers a common telephony number for you)
- the latter, but not the least: SIP is not SIP! While there is a basic protocol that is common to everyone that announces of speaking SIP, most manufacturers extend it with proprietary additions. Therefore it is worth to check whether hardphone/softphone X supports provider Y and to which extend.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Nicolas, Thank you for answering! But... You have used word `SIP` 14 times in your answer, but honestly, you did not explain **what is SIP**. Your answer could be better if you [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/740774/edit) it and add some explanation of **what is SIP**, not just listing some of it qualities.

Comment: I disagree, because the author explicitly reported that he did not understood the technical description on Wikipedia. Therefore I skipped any explanation one can find on Wikipedia and Wikipedia alike sites and gave a practical answer, including responses to all questions the author mentioned. It is sad, that it is not honoured to answer the question and another replica of Wikipedia articles is requested instead... :(